# CSS dynamic height, scroll overflow, 2 fixed height divs above and below

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm aiming for exactly this layout: http://jsfiddle.net/rQVmK/

... but with the addition of another fixed-height div above "Top" and another below "Bottom". The content container should grow/shrink in height as the window is vertically resized. Scrollbar is presented on overflow of content. An illustration (sorry, I'm unable to directly embed images as a new user):

http://i47.tinypic.com/s2bsic.gif

If possible, I'd like to achieve this with css only. A jQuery solution is undesirable, but it's an acceptable compromise if impossible with only css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution for you might be to split the top and bottom container in two horizontal parts:

```
<div id="div3">
    <div id="subfooter" style="height:15px;width:100%">Sub Footer</div>
    <div id="footer" style="height:15px;width:100%">Footer</div>
</div>
```

You have to edit this to your needs, but I think it's enough to give you an idea.

Comment: this works. it's not apparent in the problem description, but some of the surrounding elements on the actual page i'm working on have properties that make implementing this still not straightforward, but i think i can work it out by experimenting. this certainly answers what i was asking. thanks oliver.